# Properties of the sample mode for Bernoulli data

Tags: bias, estimators, bernoulli-distribution

Suppose we have a sample $X_1,...,X_n \sim \text{IID Bern}(p)$ of Bernoulli values with probability parameter $p \neq 0.5$.  Denoting the sample proportion $\hat{p}_n$ we define the **sample mode** as:

$$\widehat{\text{mode}}(\mathbf{x}_n) = \begin{cases}
0 & & \text{if } \hat{p}_n < \tfrac{1}{2}, \\[6pt]
\tfrac{1}{2} & & \text{if } \hat{p}_n = \tfrac{1}{2}, \\[6pt]
1 & & \text{if } \hat{p}_n > \tfrac{1}{2} \\[6pt]
\end{cases}$$

It's easy to see (and show) that this is a consistent estimator of the true mode of the distribution, but I'm unsure on how to 1) prove it is biased, and 2) derive an expression for the MSE.

Comment: I think that the mode is not displayed correctly. For $\hat{p}_{n}=0.5$ the mode should be $0$ or $1$ and not $0.5$

Comment: @Fiodor1234 That's a good observation.  However, there is no requirement that the value of an estimator always be a possible value of the estimand.  About the only way this estimator could be improved on would be through use of a randomized estimator in which the mode is estimated to be 0 with 50% probability and 1 with 50% probability when $\hat p_n=1/2.$  Horegivo: just start with the definition of a biased estimator.  Where does that take you?

Comment: @whuber The definition for an unbiased estimator would be $\mathbb{E}_{X|p}(\hat{mode}) = mode$. Then we should prove that the estimator is not equal to the true mode. However, how do we expand this expected value?

Comment: @Fiodor1234 Use the information: you can write down the formula for the expectation for the Binomial distribution.  It depends on how $\hat p_n$ is determined.  But you don't even need to go that far: *all you need to do is show there are cases where the expectation of $\hat p_n$ does not equal $0$ or does not equal $1.$*

Comment: @whuber but shy should i consider the expectstion of a binomial distribution?? I think I miss something

Comment: @Fiodor The sum of a sample of *iid* Bernoulli variables is a sufficient statistic--whence we can expect $\hat p_n$ to depend on it--and it has a Binomial distribution.

Comment: @whuber Oh, tell me if I understand correct so the expected value would be $0 \times \mathbb{P}(\hat{p}_{n}<0.5)+ 0.5 \times \mathbb{P}(\hat{p}_{n}=0.5)+ 1 \times  \mathbb{P}(\hat{p}_{n} >0.5)$ and I expand the probability of $\hat{p}_{n}$ as a Binomial?

Comment: @Fiodor Although the TeX is corrupted, the idea looks right.  But if you think about the terms in that expression you will discover you don't have to evaluate them in order to demonstrate bias: you only have to show two of them will be nonzero in most cases.

Answer (score 3):

Fix the sample size $n$ and let $\hat p_n$ be any function of the data whatsoever.

The data are modeled as $n$ independent Bernoulli$(p)$ variables $X_1,\ldots, X_n.$

Suppose $\hat p_n$ gives an unbiased estimator of the mode--let's call it $\tau.$ To state what that means, notice that $\tau$ partitions all possible values of the variables into three (disjoint) sets:

$$\begin{aligned}
\mathcal{E}_0 = \{(x_1,x_2,\ldots,x_n)\mid \hat p_n(x_1,\ldots,x_n) \lt \frac{1}{2}\} &; \quad \tau = 0\\
\mathcal{E}_{1/2} = \{(x_1,x_2,\ldots,x_n)\mid \hat p_n(x_1,\ldots,x_n) = \frac{1}{2}\} &; \quad\tau=\frac{1}{2} \\
\mathcal{E}_1 = \{(x_1,x_2,\ldots,x_n)\mid \hat p_n(x_1,\ldots,x_n) \gt \frac{1}{2}\}; &\quad\tau = 1.\end{aligned}$$

The expectation is the sum of the values of $\tau$ times their chances:

$$\begin{aligned}
Q(p) = E[\tau(X_1,\ldots, X_n);p] &= 0\times \Pr(\mathcal{E}_0; p) + \frac{1}{2} \times \Pr(\mathcal{E}_{1/2}; p) + 1 \times \Pr(\mathcal{E}_1; p) \\
&= \frac{1}{2} \Pr(\mathcal{E}_{1/2}; p) + \Pr(\mathcal{E}_1; p).
\end{aligned}\tag{*}$$

Because the $X_i$ are independent and equal $1$ with probability $p$ and $0$ with probability $1-p,$ the chance of any particular sequence of $n$ values $\mathbf x$ is a product of a power of $p$ (the number of ones among the components of $\mathbf x$) and a power of $(1-p)$ (the number of zeros among the components of $\mathbf x$).  *This is a polynomial function of degree at most $n.$*  Thus, the chances of each of the $\mathcal{E}_{*}$--which are finite sums of such polynomial values--are also polynomial functions of degree at most $n.$

Consider what it means for $\tau$ to be unbiased.  For all $0\lt p\lt 1/2,$ where the mode is $0,$ the expectation $(*)$ must be zero.  This implies it has more than $n$ roots.  This is impossible for a polynomial of degree $n$ or less unless it is identically zero on this interval.  *Thus, $Q$ must be the zero polynomial.*

For all $1/2\lt p \lt 1,$ where the mode is $1,$ the expectation of $(*)$ must suddenly equal one.  This is impossible: the zero polynomial evaluates to zero for *all* real arguments.

Consequently, an unbiased estimator $\tau$ of this form does not exist for any $n.$

---

Using the $\mathcal{E}_{*}$ notation it straightforward to apply the definition of mean squared error to write an expression for the MSE of $\tau.$  But this will remain abstract until you specify a particular function $\hat p_n.$  Then you can evaluate it and perhaps simplify it.